# Why is my reputation tab points higher than achievements drop-down in the top right corner?

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog, reputation-history

I am looking at my reputation today, it shows on my reputation tab that I got 295 rep today, here is the image:

[image]

As you can see, I got 295 reputation, but when I look at my achievements drop-down in the top right corner, it shows that I only got 291 reputation, as you can see below:

[image]

I personally think this is a bit confusing...

I don't think it's meant to be like this, right??..

Comment: Did you click "Show deleted posts" in your reputation tab?